# Extract texts from XIB files for translation in human readable way

Tags: iphone, localization, translation, xib, libtool

`ibtool` is the tool to extract strings from XIB files. Example command:

```
find . -name \*.xib | xargs -t -I '{}' ibtool --generate-strings-file '{}'.strings.txt '{}'
```

But output generated by ibtool is NOT READABLE for 'normal' (read: non-developers) human being.

Example:

```
/* Class = "IBUILabel"; text = "Regards:"; ObjectID = "201"; */
"201.text" = "Regards:";
```

There are few problems with it (from the perspective of translator);

1. This format is different that one expected by Localizable.strings.
2. It it confusing which texts to translate: a) this in commented line, b) one in uncommented line, c) or both maybe
3. It has just a lot of clutter.

I need XIB strings extracted in `Localizable.strings` format (strings extracted from NSLocalizableString macros using `genstrings`:

```
 "key"="to translate";
```

It there a way to make ibtool output text this way?

Comment: You're right that the generated format is a nightmare. Think we're stuck with the keys, as that is what it's matching up internally. What I find is a killer is the order of the output is alphabetic by the (random) keys - which have NO correspondence to where the strings appear in the interface, making it hard to follow. And unless I'm missing something, ibtool doesn't seem to be able to only append new strings to a manually restructured and commented file (which might help a bit). Having a universal app means sending off two equally unreadable files containing basically the same strings.

Comment: @RobGlassey I posted the working script just below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote my own script in bash, which does the following:

1. Extracts all strings from all xib files in the directory
2. Converts it to the .strings format (expected by `NSLocalizableString` macro). `"text to translate"="text to translate";` It can be used directly by your translator.Only right side, text in quotes after = needs to be edited.
3. Removes duplicates (I agree - sometimes it is not the best idea as translations may differ depending on context)
4. Removes comments (leaves just the juice)
5. Sorts alphabetically (optional)
6. Saves result to the 1 output file (all merged and ready for translation)

Script is not perfect but it works quite well.

It has a bit too long to past it here (90 lines), so here is the direct GitHub link:

https://github.com/lukaszmargielewski/extract-strings-from-xib-files/blob/master/extract-strings-from-xib-files.sh

Comment: Interesting. I've taken a different tack which involves a bit (lot) more manual work getting set up and updating (effectively creating a 'master' .strings file using our own keys, that are then mapped onto iPhone/iPad IB keys). This gives the translator a readable file, no duplication of iPhone/iPad strings if they're the same, and generates readable .strings files for each language, using the correct IB keys - though preserving our ordering and comments. It's a bit more convoluted, and I'm not done yet, but i believe it will be maintainable once initial set up is done. Lets see if it works.